# Netbeans and Intellij : Shortcut Key equivalence

Tags: java, netbeans, intellij-idea

I used Netbeans and now I will use Intellij 14.3. My problem is that I don't know JAVA shorcutkeys of Intellij. In Netbeans :

- Ctrl+Maj+i : arrage import
- sout : System.out.println
- fori : `for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)`
- Ctrl+Maj+Up/Down : Copy line
- ... .

Is there equuivalence of these shortcut on Intellij.

Comment: Go to Settings/Keymap. There is a selectbox with various predefined keymaps, one of which is Netbeans. It should provide you Netbeans style shortcuts in IntelliJ. Or you can learn the IntelliJ shortcuts as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using IntelliJ and a few of your examples are in it (`sout` and `fori` for sure)

There is also a pretty useful cheat sheet from JetBrains, you could use:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf